# How can i execute javascript of jsp throught java connection url?

Tags: java, javascript

Hi i have written my javascript code in my jsp page and i am calling my jsp through java  connection url,it is executing properly but skipping my javascript function which i have called at the time of  page load.
I am not able to understand why it is not executing my javascript.

```
try {
    URL myURL = new URL("http:localhost:8080/Approval.jsp?empCode=123&compCode=A");
    URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
    myURLConnection.connect();
} 
catch (IOException e) {   

}
```

Is there any of calling JavaScript directly through connection url.Please suggest?

Comment: `URLConnection` isn't a browser, it just downloads whatever is at the URL given. It doesn't execute anything.

Comment: there is some problem in Your Jsp .can you explain what you are doing in JSP.

Comment: @Todd i am passing values from the url and using these values inside my javascript function.Is there any other way by which i can do this?

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client, not the server. Your Java program is the client. With `URLConnection` you are essentially saying "open a connection to this server, download whatever is at this path". Nothing gets executed. Unless you have a JavaScript interpreter you can feed the JavaScript through, nothing is going to run anywhere.

Comment: @user1976940 : you can check details here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the web, JavaScript is generally included as part of HTML web pages, and is only executed within that context. Web browsers normally do this; they have built-in HTML and JavaScript (and CSS, among other things) parsers which parse the source, and built-in JavaScript engines which execute the JavaScript in the context of the web page.

The Java `URLConnection` abstraction is not a web browser and knows nothing about HTML and JavaScript; it only supports sending requests to and receiving responses from a URL. And, it doesn't even do that itself, since its `connect()` method is abstract; it relies on a (more) concrete subclass to know how to do that stuff using a specific protocol. In your case this would be `HttpURLConnection`, as your URL uses the HTTP protocol.

`HttpURLConnection` adds specific knowledge of certain HTTP features, such as HTTP status codes, but it still knows nothing about HTML and JavaScript. Thus, the end result of this is that, although your code will properly receive all the HTML and JavaScript that was generated by your JSP when building your web page, it won't be able to parse or execute it; it's basically plaintext as far as `HttpURLConnection` is concerned.

What you're looking for is a headless (GUI-less) browser library for Java. I would recommend HtmlUnit (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which is very widely-used and stable, and can do many things, including executing JavaScript.